# Keystroke Dynamics - Flight time calculating

Tags: javascript, php, html

We're doing a password authentication system with keystroke dynamics. During the registration process our system asks the user to type the password THREE TIMES, taking the latencies between each key every time and then adding them. So there's gonna be three different values for each time, and then we take an average of the three values and that will be the final value. How do I take the latencies between each key and store it in an array and calculate the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the timeStamp data in the event, you can calculate the average relatively easily by taking the difference between the current and next keystroke (if it exists). From there, you can simply average out the sum of differences by the total number of keystrokes (minus 1). NOTE: This probably isn't the most elegant solution ever, but it's a good proof of concept.

```js
/**
 * Log the keypresses
 */
var handler = function(e) {
  var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
  if (inputName == "password1") handler.data.password1.push(e);
  if (inputName == "password2") handler.data.password2.push(e);
  if (inputName == "password3") handler.data.password3.push(e);
}

// Init data
handler.data = {};
handler.data.password1 = [];
handler.data.password2 = [];
handler.data.password3 = [];

$(":password").on("keyup", handler);

/**
 * Calculate averages
 */
function getAvg(dataInput) {
  var sum = 0;
  $.each(dataInput, function(index, value) {
    if (typeof dataInput[index + 1] != 'undefined') {
      sum += (dataInput[index + 1].timeStamp - value.timeStamp);
    }
  });
  return sum / dataInput.length;
}

/**
* Run calculations
*/
$("input[type='submit']").on('click', function(e) {
  var pw1 = $("input[name='password1']"),
      pw2 = $("input[name='password2']"),
      pw3 = $("input[name='password3']");

  e.preventDefault();

  if (pw1.val().length && pw1.val() == pw2.val() && pw1.val() == pw3.val()) {
    var pw1Avg = getAvg(handler.data.password1),
      pw2Avg = getAvg(handler.data.password2),
      pw3Avg = getAvg(handler.data.password3);

    $("#output").html('PW1 Avg between key strokes: ' + Math.round(pw1Avg) + 'ms<br>' +
      'PW2 Avg between key strokes: ' + Math.round(pw2Avg) + 'ms<br>' +
      'PW3 Avg between key strokes: ' + Math.round(pw3Avg) + 'ms');

    // Reset data
    $("input[type='password']").val('');
    handler.data = {};
    handler.data.password1 = [];
    handler.data.password2 = [];
    handler.data.password3 = [];
  } else {
    $("#output").html('All passwords must match!');
  }

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
  <p>
    <input type="password" name="password1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="password" name="password2">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="password" name="password3">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit">
  </p>
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Tried the code, but it wouldn't work on my browser. I think it is something to do with the google api link in the src. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Check your console to find out

Answer (score 0):

you can create listener on every `keyDown` then get current time in milisecond using this function
`new Date().getTime()`

this is my approach.

```
    var try_counter = 0;
    var container = [[],[],[]];

    function onKeyHit(){
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        container[try_counter].push(time);
    }

    function onSumbitButtonHit(){
        try_counter++;
    }
```

then all time in milisecond will stored in array and then you can use it as you wanted